# Как в Oracle сравнить 2 поля

Tags: sql, oracle

Поля имеют тип `VARCHAR(8)`. Как можно это поле сравнить со строкой `(string)`?

```
select * from table WHERE postinfo = '12345678';
```

Где `postinfo VARCHAR(8)` не работает. Ничего не возвращает.

Comment: А так работает?

select * from table WHERE postinfo = cast('12345678' as varchar(8));

А значение 12345678 есть в базе?

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(*) from table WHERE postinfo = '12345678' and rownum = 1;
```

Eсли строки равны, то вернет `1`. Если не равны - `0`.

Comment: _Eсли строки равны, то вернет 1_, а если таких строк не одна? Условие `and rownum = 1` излишне, `count` без `group by` **всегда** вернёт одну строку. Поправте ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Сравнение выполнено верно (см. [правила сравнения символьных значений](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-A114F1F4-A08D-4107-B679-323DC7FEA31C)):

```sql
create table t1 (postinfo varchar (8));
insert into t1 values ('12345678'); 

select * from t1 where postinfo = '12345678';

POSTINFO
--------
12345678
```

Если *Ничего не возвращает*, значит колонка не содержит такого значения.
Неожидаемый результат -- проверте сравниваемые значения SQL функцией [DUMP](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DUMP.html#GUID-A05793C9-B35D-4BA7-B68C-E3693BCF47A5):

```sql
select dump (postinfo) o1,  dump ('12345678') o2 from t1;

O1                                     O2                                    
-------------------------------------- --------------------------------------
Typ=1 Len=8: 49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56   Typ=96 Len=8: 49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56
```